# External variable mex-file

Tags: c, matlab, mex

So I'm trying to create a Mex-File which opens a connection to a datalogger and I would like to avoid having to pass the device ID back and forth. I tried using an external variable to store the device ID however I seem to be unable to compile.
So what I am trying to do looks somewhat like this:
File A opens the connection:

```
#include ...

int devID;

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{   
    devID = openConnection();
    return;
}
```

and file B should then be able to access devID via:

```
#include ...

extern int devID;

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{   
    closeConnection(devID);
    return;
}
```

file A compiles fine however when I try to compile file B I get:

```
 unresolved external symbol "int devID"
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: are you including file A in file B? have you tried compiling them together?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the variable persistent with [mexMakeArrayPersistent](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexmakearraypersistent.html). I think you would need to use only one `mexFunction()` though, which would be used to open or close the connection, depending on an input flag.

Alternatively, maybe there is a function from the datalogger that returns the device ID when a connection exists, e.g. `devID = checkConnection();`